# How to generate cucumber Extent reports html for every test case

Tags: cucumber, extentreports

I am trying to use Cucumber Extent Reports to generate my html report. I want to create a consolidated HTML report for the overall test execution and individual HTML report for each test case. I am not able to create individual HTML for every test case but able to create the consolidated HTML by using the following
plugin ={"com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html"}
How to add the same for generating the HTML for individual test cases? Can someone please help me out

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROw52.png)

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want an individual one for each test case since the consolidated report only shows one test case at a time anyway, but it would really be as simple as recreating the extent report for each test case with a different filename instead of the usual process of creating one, then creating multiple tests.

Comment: Hey Bill.Thanks for the response . I have written a wrapper for multi threading that would run the scenarios in the feature files in parallel. In this case, I am generating consolidated Extent report but I would require individual Extent report for every test case so that i can upload them to ALM against each test case.I have added the screenshot of the HTML report that i  generate now

Comment: You might need to create one wrapper object for each thread.  I'm currently running into something similar with my own extent reports wrapper class.

Comment: Will you be able to share the Extent Reports wrapper class code ? I tired adding the thread level report like this  :                                                   
plugin="com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/consolidatedreport.html"} ,plugin="com.vimalselvam.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/tc01_report.html"}  . "tc01_report.html" would be dynamic and would change for every new thread but it did not work

Comment: I'm afraid I can't share it as it is the property of the company I work for.  It doesn't work the same way as the Cucumber listener, I mostly use JBehave so I had to write my own class to make the BDD style of the report easy to implement.  In my case, I create an object of my classtype and pass it the webdriver for screen capture purposes, then assign the html output to that instance.  I don't know how the cucumber hooks work, perhaps it doesn't allow that level of customization.

Comment: No problem Bill. Thanks for the response